# microsoft office document imaging on windows 2008 64 bit

Tags: windows-server-2008, ocr, office-2007, modi

I have done document imaging on windows 7 with MODI in office 2007 and it is successful. But when I install the same office 2007 with MODI onto windows server 2008, it does not work with my program anymore. it is throwing a comexception of "(0xc6c80001): Object hasn't been initialized and can't be used yet at MODI.IDocument.OCR". I did not change anything for the codes at all. Anyone has any idea?